# Custom PayPal Checkout for subscription plan

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to build a custom PayPal checkout for a single product (subscription plan).

On successful purchase I need to save the current date +30 days to the user profile as well as upgrade the user role to "premium". This part is no problem but I'm having trouble finding how and what I need to use from PayPal.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Is the PayPal IPN service still a thing, or is it legacy?

I checked out some PayPal WordPress plugins but they offer too much esp. an own member solution or integration with WooCommerce, which I don't need.  I only need a plugin that handles the checkout and gives me the chance to hook some custom actions on some events for example the successful purchase.

Comment: I would consider perhaps Stripe subscription. The integration is pretty simple and tones of rerssources exist on it.

Comment: yes i considered it but paypal would be the number one gateway we need. do you know any other payment gateways that have an easy integration and can give responses back that have paypal included in their supported payment methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use something old like PayPal IPN. Use the current Subscriptions API, and webhooks for event notifications.

Subscriptions are documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

And to subscribe to webhooks for later event notification, see [webhook event names for subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions).

---

The Webhook documentation mentions using REST SDKs. Those SDKs are deprecated, use HTTPS API calls.